# JavaScript single line comment starting with -->

Tags: javascript, html, comments

I know that JavaScript single line comments start with `//` and end on a line break, multi-line comments start with `/*` and end with `*/`, and that HTML comments start with `<!--` and end with `-->`.

What I didn't knew is that apparently starting a JavaScript line with `-->` creates a single line comment (that ends on a line break).

`//` can be used in front of code but for `-->` to work it can't have any running code behind:

```js
console.log('Start'); // normal comment
--> weird comment
/*
  Can't have running code at the start
  of the line or it throws the error:
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
  (but it can have space characters)
*/
console.log('End');
```

My question is if this is normal behavior or just some glitch, since I found no information on it.
It's definitely connected with the HTML comment block/tag, probably unintended and/or a glitch.

Tested with the Google Chrome browser in a HTML file and on the developer tools' console.

Comment: Doesn't JS ignores the closing characters of HTML-style comments?

Comment: @AndyG I expected to see that, but I believe this is a different question.